# Java - Alternate While loop declaration

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm currently working on a project out of a text book and I've had an obscure problem with a while loop. The code from the text book is as follows;

```
while(getImage().getWidth(applet) <= 0);
double x = applet.getSize().width/2 - width()/2;
double y = applet.getSize().height/2 - height()/2;
at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
```

I've never seen a while loop declared with a semi-colon on the end, so I interpreted my code to be the standard;

```
while(getImage().getWidth(applet) <= 0) {
    double x = applet.getSize().width/2 - width()/2;
    double y = applet.getSize().height/2 - height()/2;
    at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x, y);
}
```

Can someone please explain the difference between the two? I changed my code to be like the first and my program worked just fine, however I don't understand the difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your change has changed the logic of the code. The idea of the `while(getImage().getWidth(applet) <= 0);` is to wait until the applets width size gets>0. And after that is the rest of the code proceeded. (It might wait for another process to init the applet).

Answer (score 4):

A semicolon is an empty statement. You can use it when evaluating the continuation condition of your `while` loop has a side effect: the loop will produce a chain of side effects that invalidate the loop condition upon completion, or run forever.

For example, if `getImage()` gets you a new image every time you call it, the loop will continue until the returned image has width that is `<= 0`.

Here is a simple example of using a `while` loop to find the first character after `a` in a string:

```
int pos = 0;
String s = "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
while (i != s.length() && s.charAt(i++) != 'a')
    ;
```

Since reading code like that may be confusing, it is typical to place the semicolon on a separate line, indented as a loop statement.

Answer (score 1):

It is intentional; **the image is loaded asynchroneously** in a background process and [getWidth(ImageObserver)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Image.html#getWidth%28java.awt.image.ImageObserver%29) in effect asks whether the image already can give a width. This is simply a so called busy loop. First getWidth is -1.

This is bad coding style, and also getWidth can be known where the getHeigth still is not fully read.

This stems from the first period of java with slow internet connections.

Better is using the [ImageObserver](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html) callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

The semicolon is the end of the while loop in the first example.  It's sometimes useful to have a single-line loop like that, but it's also a common mistake.

If it's intentional, then it looks like maybe this code is waiting for another thread to change the width of the applet in question. This isn't a great way to do something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's an infinite loop.  Not sure if typo or not and I'd write same way you did.

I suspect this is a test to see if you catch the error and you did so congrats!

SEE: http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/SWE/JavaPitfalls.html

Comment: like Mike F. stated, it could be blocking until some event occurs but if in textbook, it might be designed to stump you and see if you catch it and correct like you did.  Here's an article for ya: http://users.csc.calpoly.edu/~jdalbey/SWE/JavaPitfalls.html